# How ClassicShell Autostarts? Can Autoruns detect it?

Tags: windows-8.1

I use Sysinternals Autoruns every weekend for system checkup and I just realized that [ClassicShell](http://www.classicshell.net) is not in Autoruns' list (There are no entries from IvoSoft or the installation folder); while ClassicShell is set to start automatically at user logon. Checked the process with ProcessExplorer and it says the parent is `explorer.exe`.
I'm confused:
How ClassicShell Autostarts?

Comment: Are you running the latest version (13.81)? Earlier versions missed entries. It's also a good idea to run it as Administrator, as some entries are missed otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Autoruns 13.81 as Admin, `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: thanks, Updated Autoruns and now it's there. So the problem was an outdated version of Autoruns.

Answer (score 0):

To check for startup applications in Windows 10, Right click on the taskbar and select Task Manager. In Task Manager select 'more details' then click the startup tab. All the startup applications are listed there.